# why do I get this strange looking image after a boolean operation of 2 cylinders?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have used boolean difference to merge the 2 cylinders. However, the resulting image does not look healthy...I would like to fix this before I move to sculpting
Have i missed a setting?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe show how your topology looks like and what you're trying to achieve, if you want to make a hollow cylinder you can simply extrude a cylinder

Comment: It looks like Z-clipping, maybe there is second object left in there or there are duplicated faces... show us topology, try to move it or merge vertices by distance